# How calculate text position of one element inside another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset

I try to calculate text position of one HTML element inside another in the Dom (without HTML entities). For example:

```
<body>


  <div class="texOne">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    <div>

    <div class="texTwo">
    Excepteur <mark id="example">sint</mark> occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  <div>

  <script>
  var offsets=$("div.textTwo").calculateOffsetsOf("#example");

  //Result
  offset.start=10
  offset.end=14
  </script>

</body>
```

How I can find these offsets with the best possible performance?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry too much about performance at this point in your coding career -- focus on what makes sense.

You can get parent's inner html with jQuery's `.html()` method:

```
var parentHtml = $("div.texTwo").html()
// -> Excepteur  <mark id="example">sint</mark>  occaecat cupidatat non proident...
```

Do the same for the child's outer html:

```
var childHtml = $("#example").outerHTML()
// -> <mark id="example">sint</mark>
```

And you should be able to calculate the starting point.  The ending point will just be the starting point + length of child's text.

Comment: This is not a solution. It gets html entities that change the original text position. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. You could easily build a method to give start and end like you requested. Is there something about it you don't understand?